# Rebuild Json response with php array

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I get some data from an API in `JSON`.  A typical response looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1918443",
    "comp_id": "1322",
    "formatted_date": "20.04.2016",
    "season": "2015/2016",
    "week": "32",
    "venue": "De Grolsch Veste (Enschede)",
    "venue_id": "1067",
    "venue_city": "Enschede",
    "status": "FT",
    "timer": "",
    "time": "18:45",
    "localteam_id": "13460",
    "localteam_name": "Twente",
    "localteam_score": "2",
    "visitorteam_id": "13253",
    "visitorteam_name": "Excelsior",
    "visitorteam_score": "0",
    "ht_score": "[0-0]",
    "ft_score": "[2-0]",
    "et_score": null,
    "penalty_local": null,
    "penalty_visitor": null, 

etc ...
```

This response has multiple games (the above response is only one game).
I have an `iOS` app that works with other APIs (I don't want to change the app code).  The old app has all games inside an array like this :

```
"matches": [
    {
    "id": "1918443",
    "comp_id": "1322",
    "formatted_date": "20.04.2016",
    "season": "2015/2016",
    "week": "32",
    "venue": "De Grolsch Veste (Enschede)",
    "venue_id": "1067",
    "venue_city": "Enschede",
    "status": "FT",
    "timer": "",
    "time": "18:45",
    "localteam_id": "13460",
    "localteam_name": "Twente",
    "localteam_score": "2",
    "visitorteam_id": "13253",
    "visitorteam_name": "Excelsior",
    "visitorteam_score": "0",
    "ht_score": "[0-0]",
    "ft_score": "[2-0]",
    "et_score": null,
    "penalty_local": null,
    "penalty_visitor": null,
```

So what I want to do is put the first `JSON` response inside an array "matches" how can i do this with a `foreach` ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to decode the json response and put it into a new array keyed with 'matches' like so:

```
$json = //... your json response here
$games = ['matches' => json_decode($json, true)];

foreach ($games as $game) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you will need a `foreach` here, but I might not understand you fully. What you want to do first, is decode that json into the PHP array using `json_decode`, and then create a new array and put the first decoded array into *matches*. Example:

```
$gameData = json_decode(/* your json string from above */);
$games = [
    "matches" => $gameData
];
echo json_encode($matches);
```

If you now with to itterate this array you simply need to put `$games["matches"]` into foreach.